# Export the load balancers present in AWS to a certain EKS Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

Is it possible in AWS to export the load balancers present in AWS to a certain EKS Cluster?

I would need to export a list of LoadBalancers associated with the EKS Cluster in order to indicate which ones have public or private access.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "export" in this context? Also if you have tried anything already, please also share that.

Comment: How to export I think about listing, visualizing.

I need to know the load balancers that were created by EKS, a list/relationship.

What I did so far was to list the loadbalancers on the console but I couldn't relate.

Comment: For NLB services, you could run something like `kubectl get svc -A -o=jsonpath="{.items[*]['status.loadBalancer']}"` This would give you the URL of the load balancer at least. You should be able to do a similar thing for ALBs and ingress objects.